# vagrant package command fails

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to create a vagrant box of a VirtualBox Ubuntu VM on my MacBook Pro. When I run the command I get an error that I don't understand. I've tried rebuilding the virtual machine. I've tried different virtual machines in different states. I keep hitting this brick wall.

It looks like VBoxManage tries to create a temporary file for the package process, but the file can't be written for some reason. This also happened on my Ubuntu laptop. So that's really interesting and makes me wonder if it is a problem with VBoxManage itself, however, it doesn't seem that many people are having this specific issue (though the error code "code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004)" is relatively common.)

Here is the output of my command:

```
earthmant$ vagrant package --base 64precise6
==> 64precise6: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
64precise6: Guest communication could not be established! This is usually because
64precise6: SSH is not running, the authentication information was changed,
64precise6: or some other networking issue. Vagrant will force halt, if
64precise6: capable.
==> 64precise6: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> 64precise6: Exporting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["export", "64precise6", "--output",         "/Users/earthmant/.vagrant.d/tmp/1417878317/box.ovf"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Appliance write failed
VBoxManage: error: File not accessible or erroneous file contents
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component Appliance, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleExportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 1121 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that a lot of people explicitly state that when you create the VM in VirtualBox, you should use the vmdk file format for the disk. I had used qcow. When I rebuilt the VM with vmdk, vagrant package succeeded.

Comment: I ran into the same error (with VirtualBox 5.0.12 and Vagrant 1.7.4). It turns out that the guest was defined using a qcow2 disk, and packaging another guest that was defined with a vmdk disk worked fine.